# SpriteComponent positioning with Flame

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

**UPDATE**: I created a smaller example that probably better illustrates the problem in this issue: https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/issues/200

**short version:**

I'm instantiating `SpriteComponents` at the positions `(50, 50), (50, 100), (100, 50), (100, 100).`

However, when rendered they look like this:
[image]

What is producing this strange offset? How do I correctly render `SpriteComponents`?

**longer version (with code):**
I would like to test the performance of flame by implementing something like [bunnymark](https://github.com/pixijs/bunny-mark).
As a first attempt at saving performance, I'm loading a single `Sprite` and using it to produce many `SpriteComponents`.

The `SpriteComponent` is wrapped in a `Bunny` class. For now it does nothing, eventually it will handle movement:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flame/components/component.dart';
import 'package:flame/sprite.dart';

class Bunny {
  SpriteComponent bunny;

  Bunny(Sprite bunnySprite, double x, double y, double w, double h)
      : this.bunny =
            SpriteComponent.fromSprite(w, h, bunnySprite) {
    bunny.x = x;
    bunny.y = y;
  }

  void render(Canvas c) {
    bunny.render(c);
  }

  void update(double t) {}
}
```

The bunnies are instantiated in my game class:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:bunnymark/components/bunny.dart';
import 'package:flame/flame.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame/sprite.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class BunnyMark extends Game {
  Size screenSize;
  List<Bunny> bunnies;
  Sprite bunnySprite;

  BunnyMark() {
    initialize();
  }

  void initialize() async {
    resize(await Flame.util.initialDimensions());

    bunnies = List<Bunny>();
    bunnySprite = Sprite('rabbitv3_tron.png');

    bunnies.add(Bunny(bunnySprite, 50, 50, 30, 30));
    bunnies.add(Bunny(bunnySprite, 50, 100, 30, 30));
    bunnies.add(Bunny(bunnySprite, 100, 100, 30, 30));
    bunnies.add(Bunny(bunnySprite, 100, 50, 30, 30));
  }

  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    Rect bgRect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
    Paint bgPaint = Paint();
    bgPaint.color = Color(0xff000000);
    canvas.drawRect(bgRect, bgPaint);

    bunnies.forEach((bunny) {
      bunny.render(canvas);
    });
  }

  void update(double t) {
    bunnies.forEach((bunny) => bunny.update(t));
  }

  void resize(Size size) {
    screenSize = size;
    super.resize(size);
  }
}
```

The game is started from main.dart:

```
import 'package:bunnymark/bunnymark.dart';
import 'package:flame/util.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Util flameUtil = Util();
  await flameUtil.fullScreen();
  await flameUtil.setOrientation(DeviceOrientation.portraitUp);

  BunnyMark game = BunnyMark();
  runApp(game.widget);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `Game` and not `BaseGame` (which would do that for you), you are responsible on your `render` implementation to reset the canvas every sprite.

Components are allowed to make any modifications they desire on the Canvas, and BaseGame (or in your case, Game) is required to reset.

So when you do

```
bunnies.forEach((bunny) {
  bunny.render(canvas);
});
```

You probably want to do something like:

```
bunnies.forEach((bunny) {
  canvas.save();
  bunny.render(canvas);
  canvas.restore();
});
```

Or, as an alternative, take a look at the `BaseGame` class that solves a lot of those problems for you :)